# Wrapper around ssh causes AppleEvent handler to fail

Tags: command-line, ssh, script

I have the script that I've pasted lower down in my path and named `ssh`. The idea is that it changes the colour of the terminal based on which host I'm ssh-ed into. This worked fine for a long time, but recently git has given me the error message

```
229:235: execution error: Terminal got an error: AppleEvent handler failed. (-10000)
```

When I'm using SSH directly, everything is fine, but something about other applications calling ssh is causing issues. When I rename this file so that `/usr/bin/ssh` is used instead, git works fine. I don't think that it's due to git not receiving the return value, as I'm passing that onwards.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

This is the wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
##
## Author: Darrin Skinner -- skinner@skinner.com
##
## https://kitepwr.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/add-color-to-your-ssh-sessions-mac-osx/
##
## This changes the terminal color depending on the ssh target environment
## and it changes it back to the original color when ssh exits
##
## In the case statement below, provide a search pattern
## and a Terminal Profile Name to use for each server.
##

HOSTNAME=$@

case $HOSTNAME  in
    murk*)        COLOR="Murk"      ;; 
    fog*)         COLOR="Fog"       ;; 
    *)            COLOR="ssh"       ;; ## Everything else
esac

ORIG_COLOR=`set_term_color "$COLOR"`
/usr/bin/ssh $@
RET_VAL=$?
ORIG_COLOR=`set_term_color "$ORIG_COLOR"`

return RET_VAL
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this on the source machine, you should be doing it on the host.  If you are connecting to a shell prompt on the host, this is easily done.